# Many to Many represented as columns

Tags: sql-server, many-to-many

I have a table representing employees. I have a second table representing various employee profiles, e.g. Employee, Team Leader, Manager, Executive etc. I have a third that maps an employee to a profile in a many-to-many relationship, i.e. an employee can belong to both an 'Employee' profile and a 'Manager' profile.

How can I get a return that shows every employee in my first column and then subsequent columns representing each profile with a Yes-No (or similar) denoting if that employee belongs to each particular profile?

Comment: could you paste your table details to make answering a touch easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with joins and aggregation:

```
select e.employee_id,
       max(case when p.profile_name = 'Employee' then 1 else 0 end) as Employee,
       max(case when p.profile_name = 'Manager' then 1 else 0 end) as Manager,
       . . . 
from employees e left outer join
     employee_profile ep
     e.employee_id = ep.employee_id left outer join
     profile p
     on ep.profile_id = p.profile_id
group by e.employee_id;
```

The data structure itself seems pretty reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

I think it'd be worthwhile a redesign to remove the many to many that you have.

If they have matching primary/foreign keys you could

```
Select * from Table1, Table2 Where Table1ID = Table2ID
```